# What happens with SignalR load balanced on Azure across autoscale instances when downscaling?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, signalr

Azure websites can be set up to autoscale depending on the load. Consider the following scenario:

Normally I run only 2 instances, but can scale up to 10 if need be. Traffic is high so I have 10 instances, multiple clients make the websocket connection with instances 3-8. Traffic dies down and instances come back down to 2.

What happens with the clients connected to instances 3-8?

Comment: What SignalR backplane are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Service Bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR attempts to open a socket connection to a specific server. As a result, if that specific server gets torn down (as in the case of an Azure App Service scale down) then that client connection would get closed.

You can handle SignalR lifetime events within your JavaScript to re-establish a connection when this happens in order to minimize impact to the user.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

For example, if you normally run two instances and you have 10 users connected. These 10 users have SignalR connections on instances #1 and 2. Then auto-scale triggers and now all of a sudden a third instance is provisioned. Ten more users come and they get SignalR connections on instance #1, 2 and 3. Five users leave and auto-scale, scales back down to two instances. The remaining 5 users that had SignalR connections to the third instance would have a closed connection. You would need to handle the close lifecycle event on the client to attempt to re-initiate a SignalR connection on instance #1 or 2.

I assume you have configured a backplane otherwise you'd probably be asking, "why are my users sporadically not getting messages?!". :)

Here's a [nice article](http://scottcodes.net/signalr-load-balancing) that I've found useful in understanding SignalR.